# Julia calling Fortran. signal (11): Segmentation fault error

Tags: fortran, julia, gfortran

I am using a very large code in Fortran. It is called `sapick6.f90`. If I compile this code:

```
gfortran -O3 -o sapick6 sapick6.f90
```

and run it:

```
./sapick6
```

I have always the same exact result (as expected). It has random number subroutines, but the seed, at the beginning is always the same, as it reads input parameters from a file.

Results are:

```
 Mean window energy:          1.84019
 Final window energy:        19.98531
 Qe: SNR (Ursin):            18.53402
 Rc: c_mean/c_mean_noise:   -53.57054
 e_tmean:                     0.00000
 Mean weighted az. (r>0.5):  19.71334
```

always.

Now, I change this code initial line, from

```
 PROGRAM sapick6
    USE nrtype
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: i,ii,iii,j,jj,ijk,k,n
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: mp = 5, np = 10
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: imax = 5001,jmax = 8,kmax = 251
    INTEGER :: NTRACES, NSAMP

...code....
...code...

end PROGRAM
```

to simply:

```
 SUBROUTINE sapick6
    USE nrtype
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER :: i,ii,iii,j,jj,ijk,k,n
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: mp = 5, np = 10
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: imax = 5001,jmax = 8,kmax = 251
    INTEGER :: NTRACES, NSAMP

...code....
...code...

end SUBROUTINE
```

note that I only changed `program` to `subroutine`. When compiled as a library:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC sapick6.f90 -o sapick6.so
```

and running this with julia (first time):

```
julia> function callsapick()
       t=ccall((:sapick6_,"./sapick6.so"),Void,(),)
       return
       end
callsapick (generic function with 1 method)

julia> callsapick()

 Mean window energy:          1.84019
 Final window energy:        19.98531
 Qe: SNR (Ursin):            18.53402
 Rc: c_mean/c_mean_noise:   -53.57054
 e_tmean:                     0.00000
 Mean weighted az. (r>0.5):  19.71334
```

and running this on julia (second time):

```
julia> callsapick()

signal (11): Violación de segmento
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
sapick6_ at ./sapick6.so (unknown line)
callsapick at ./REPL[1]:2
unknown function (ip: 0x7f8ec525e4af)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/gf.c:1933
do_call at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/interpreter.c:75
eval at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/interpreter.c:242
jl_interpret_toplevel_expr at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/interpreter.c:34
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/toplevel.c:577
jl_toplevel_eval_in at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/builtins.c:496
eval at ./boot.jl:235
unknown function (ip: 0x7f8ed988439f)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/gf.c:1933
eval_user_input at ./REPL.jl:66
unknown function (ip: 0x7f8ed98f21cf)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/gf.c:1933
macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:97 [inlined]
#1 at ./event.jl:73
unknown function (ip: 0x7f8ec52572af)
jl_call_fptr_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:339 [inlined]
jl_call_method_internal at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia_internal.h:358 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/gf.c:1933
jl_apply at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/julia.h:1424 [inlined]
start_task at /home/centos/buildbot/slave/package_tarball64/build/src/task.c:267
unknown function (ip: 0xffffffffffffffff)
Allocations: 1178414 (Pool: 1177210; Big: 1204); GC: 0

 Mean window energy:          1.20471
 Final window energy:        20.11686
 Qe: SNR (Ursin):             2.15156
 Rc: c_mean/c_mean_noise:   -32.36376
 e_tmean:                     0.00000
 Mean weighted az. (r>0.5):   6.55283
```

So I get a different result, and even worst, a segmentation fault!

What is going on?

Comment: On my Julia v0.6.2, the [hello world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_examples#Fortran_90) example works when I change `program` to read `subroutine`. Are you sure it is the problem?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin Not at all. Changing the word "program" to "subroutine" is the only way I found to compile the program as a library and be able to call it from Julia. The problem is that when I call the subroutine sapick6.f90, the first time I get the same results as if I run the code directly from fortran, but when I run it the second time(just after the first), I get a different result and a segmentation fault. I would expect the same result allways! why is it changing? why is it unstable? and why the segmentation fault? those are my quiestions..

Comment: Hard to say without a complete analysis of all the code. But as a possibility, many random number generator codes have an initialization routine that is supposed to be called once, then the generator status is maintained in static variables for when random numbers are requested. By turning the main program into a subroutine and calling it twice, you may be forcing two calls to the initialization routine causing unexpected results.

Comment: You mention the code reads in parameters from a file. Most large codes are designed this way. Is not one of those parameters a random number seed so you can get different results without recompiling the code? Random number generators work this way by design so you can replicate results if necessary.

Comment: @DanSp. Indeed, in the file, one of the parameters is the SEED. So without changing it, the results has to be the same. In fact, if a run the program in the console, I have the same result independently of how many times I run it. Now, when I call this code from Julia, that doesn't happend. I call it once, and the outcome is Ok, I call it again and now It is wrong... So, I have to exit Julia every time I want the good result... There is something wrong that I don't understand..

Comment: @DanSp. About your first comment, The code runs just fine in console. I don't think there's a problem with it. This program has NOT an initialization subroutine (as those found in modern NR), but instead it has the standar ran1.f subroutine found in the "old NR book. It is initialized every time you put a negative integer number throught it. As these number is read at the begining of the code, I supose the result has to be the same in every call... right? Is there any command in Julia to clean all the system at the end of a  function? I will try "clear(all)" at the end of the julia calling....

Comment: Debug idea: compile the code as `subroutine sapick6` (in a module!) and write a program `program test ; use sapick6_module ; implicit none ; call sapick6 ; call sapick6 ; end program test`. If this produces the error, at least you will rule out the Julia interface as creating the problem.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Such a great idea! I have just finished with that experiment. and now, in fortran console, the two consecutive "call sapick6 ()" inside the main program give the two different results I had with Julia. So, .. how is that possible? at the beginning of sapick6 subroutine, a file is read with the seed... It is always the same seed!!!!. How is that possible? why is the second "call" conditioned by the first?.... how can I remedy that?

Comment: As Dan Sp mentioned, your code might have an "internal state" that is not reset between subroutine calls, for instance in the rng that could initialized only once but other possibilities exist.

Comment: For further diagnosis, you sould design a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance a routine that reads the seed and outputs the first random number. Call it twice in a program and have a look at the results.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Indeed. I will proceed as you suggest, but it will take time to think of an experiment adequate for this purpose. In the mid-time, I have an idea of what can be going wrong... many subroutines uses the "SAVE" statement, and I think the second "call" is taking some of the saved values from the first. Now, I have read about this, And found that this can be remedied by using these saved variables on a structure like a "derived data_type". Would the behavior of this structure be as the "save" statement during the firts call, but reseted for the second?

Comment: save acts between calls, so your question is a bit ill-posed. An example: `integer :: i = 1` will be "saved" but two separate lines `integer :: i ; i = 1` will set i to 1 on every entry.

Comment: You should not better to modify your old fortran coffee.  Julia is very good at running external programs. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/running-external-programs/#Running-External-Programs-1